# SpringBoot scheduler expression to run twice a day

Tags: spring-boot, cron

Hi i am using the below SpringBoot cron expression to run my scheduled job twice a day. It should run at 10am and 4pm

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 10,16 * * *")
```

I started my Springboot application at 3:30pm and it trigged the scheduled job at 4pm but then next day it didn't trigger the job at 10am

Is there any thing wrong with my cron expression above? Please note that this is not the unix cron expression. It takes only 6 params as per SpringBoot docs.

Comment: you must check that the task has already been finished before 10am

Comment: What does it mean? It is supposed to start at 10am again.. and i can confirm it never run in between 4pm to 10am

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cron expression is correct. There should be other problems that cause your cron job does not run as expected.

Internally ,Spring uses `CronSequenceGenerator` to generate the next trigger time for a cron expression. To prove that your cron expression is configured correctly, you can try to play with `CronSequenceGenerator`.

For example , the following function will simply print out the next 10 trigger time of a cron expression :

```
 public static void printNextTriggerTime(String cronExpression, LocalDateTime currentTime) {
        CronSequenceGenerator generator = new CronSequenceGenerator(cronExpression);
        Date d = Date.from(currentTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            d = generator.next(d);
            System.out.println(d);
        }
    }
```

And if I input your cron expression and starting time :

```
    printNextTriggerTime("0 0 10,16 * * *", LocalDateTime.of(2019, 8, 20, 15, 30, 0));
```

It will output:

```
Tue Aug 20 16:00:00 HKT 2019
Wed Aug 21 10:00:00 HKT 2019
Wed Aug 21 16:00:00 HKT 2019
Thu Aug 22 10:00:00 HKT 2019
Thu Aug 22 16:00:00 HKT 2019
Fri Aug 23 10:00:00 HKT 2019
Fri Aug 23 16:00:00 HKT 2019
Sat Aug 24 10:00:00 HKT 2019
Sat Aug 24 16:00:00 HKT 2019
Sun Aug 25 10:00:00 HKT 2019
```

Comment: Thanks this make sense and i could verify the results too with this. Actually i changed the expression today and can see it running on scheduled time, there must be some different issue then.

Comment: this helped me out a lot, thank you very much